# Return a struct which has a reference to a value which will be dropped

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have problems with my code in rust. Ofc it has to to with borrowing. This is my first try at own code after reading the rust book.

The thing is, I kinda understand what the problem is and have an idea how to solve it, but that solution would end in some ugly structured code.

I have a struct which implements following method:

```
pub(crate) fn get_calendar_events(&self, name: &str) -> Result<Vec<Calendar>,String> {
    let xml: String = self.get_calendar_xml(name).map_err(|e|{
        format!("Error extracting xml: {}", e)
    })?;

    let event_responses: Vec<Responses> = self.parse_event_responses(&xml);

    let mut events: Vec<Calendar> = Vec::new();

    for response in event_responses {
        let ics_result: Result<Response,Error> = self.webdav_client.get(&format!("{}/{}", self.url, response.href));
        let ics_response: Response = ics_result.map_err(|e|{
            format!("Error in ics result: {}", e)
        })?;
        let mut ics: String = ics_response.text().map_err(|e|{
            format!("Error in ics response: {}", e)
        })?;

        let calendar_result: Result<Calendar<'_>, String> = read_calendar(&ics);

        let calendar_event: Calendar = calendar_result.map_err(|e|{
            format!("Error reading calendar event: {}", e)
        })?;
        events.push(calendar_event);
    }
    Ok(events)
}
```

Inside the loop I have the variable `ics` . The method `read_calendar`is from the crate "iCalendar" and takes a `&str` as argument. I want unpack the result from `read-calendar` and push the `calendar_event` in a Vec which I want the method to return.

I get the error, that `ics` will be dropped at the end of the loop and `calendar_result` (and `calendar_event`) can't reference that value when it is dropped.

The only idea I have to solve this error is to outsource the complete loop to the place where I need access to the `calendar_event`, but this will end up in some chaotic looking code.

Coming from java I probably approach things too much in that typical object-oriented way and have to try to rethink my approach.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch How will that help? Surely the cloned `String` will get dropped just the same?

Comment: Yeah, i tried cloning, but the clone will also be dropped. Same result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like the issue is that the `Calendar` struct doesn't take ownership of the input string, it just keeps the reference.

I'm not super familiar with the `icalendar` library, but it looks like there are two different `Calendar` structs: [icalendar::parser::Calendar<'a>](https://docs.rs/icalendar/0.15.4/icalendar/parser/struct.Calendar.html#impl-From%3CCalendar%3C%27_%3E%3E-for-Calendar), and [icalendar::Calendar](https://docs.rs/icalendar/0.15.4/icalendar/struct.Calendar.html#impl-From%3CC%3E-for-Calendar).

I did some tweaking on my machine to remove the webdav stuff so it would build, but it seems that using the `icalendar::Calendar` variant will compile:

```
use icalendar::{parser::read_calendar, Calendar as CalendarOwned};

pub fn get_calendar_events(name: &str) -> Result<Vec<CalendarOwned>, String> {
    let mut events: Vec<CalendarOwned> = Vec::new();

    loop {
        let mut ics: String = "thing".to_owned();

        let calendar_result = read_calendar(&ics);

        let calendar_event = calendar_result
            .map_err(|e| format!("Error reading calendar event: {}", e))
            .unwrap();

        events.push(calendar_event.into());

        break;
    }

    Ok(events)
}
```

This version of the struct *looks* to be mostly similar, but taking ownership of its component parts instead of borrowing them. Like I say though, i'm not familliar with this library so I could be talking rubbish.

Comment: Yes, your are right. Using the other calendar works. `read_calendar` still return the icalendar::parser::Calendar but calling `calendar_event.into()` converts it to the other type. Using the other Calendar makes some calls at other places in my code invalid. I have to look how to handle that, but thanks for your help.I now know it has to do with how the calendar structs are build in the icalendar crate.